# Android WebView Not showing Anything

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to use webView to show a URL in android app.

If I try with this URL-

> http://stackoverflow.com

I am getting this-
[image]

But if I am trying with this-

> https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F8111706%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-3aK27&color=e2ef3a&auto_play=false&show_artwork=false

I am getting this-

[image]

What I have done is-

**Activity**-

```
package com.appnucleus.abrarjahin.hello8920;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if ( isNetworkAvailable() )     //check if internet available or not
        {
            Toast.makeText(
                                ActivityMain.this,
                                "Internet Connected",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
            WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl(getString(R.string.sound_cloud_url));
        }
        else    //Not connected
        {
            Toast.makeText(
                    ActivityMain.this,
                    "Internet Disconnected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
        }
    }

    //<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    //<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable()
    {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }
}
```

**Layout**-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.appnucleus.abrarjahin.hello8920.ActivityMain">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**-

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name" translatable="false">Hello 8920</string>
    <string name="sound_cloud_url">https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F8111706%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-3aK27&amp;color=e2ef3a&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=false</string>
    <string name="test_url">http://stackoverflow.com/</string>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appnucleus.abrarjahin.hello8920">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityMain">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone please help why I am getting a blank page?

Comment: can you trying setting width and height of webview to match_parent?

Comment: which device are you using? I have faced similar issue on Nexus. It can be device specific.

Comment: Have open the url in browser?

Comment: Have you tried my solution ?

Comment: Actually the thing is, all other links are working except that given link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    **webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());**
    String url = "https://www.google.co.in";
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

This may helps you.

Comment: why a new instance of WebViewClient is necessary?

Comment: This line  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); worked for me, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add `WebViewClient` on **WebView** and check what error you are getting.

How to set it ?

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                Log.e("Error", description);
           }

   });
```

Hope this will make sense.

Comment: Please read my code carefully. I am already doing that. All links are working except that link

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `onReceivedSslError` in you `webViewClient`.

```
    aboutALCWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.d("Ssl Error:",handler.toString() + "error:" +  error);
        handler.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me setting `loadWithOverviewMode` to `false` resolved the issue.
Even Though setting back to `true` now doesn't make a difference anymore...

Conrete Code to set `loadWithOverviewMode` (Kotlin):

```
webview.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = false
```

Answer (score -4):

**Try this Code:-**

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if ( isNetworkAvailable() )     //check if internet available or not
        {
            Toast.makeText(
                                ActivityMain.this,
                                "Internet Connected",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
            WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl(getString(R.string.sound_cloud_url));
        }
        else    //Not connected
        {
            Toast.makeText(
                    ActivityMain.this,
                    "Internet Disconnected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
        }
    }

    //<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    //<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable()
    {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }

 public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain please? @anonymous

Comment: Please add explanation

Answer (score -5):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```